# electron autoUpdater returns empty error on mac on setFeedURL

Tags: macos, electron

I am trying to set autoUpdater for mac

```
var os = require('os');
var electron = require('electron');
var app = electron.app;
var autoUpdater = electron.autoUpdater;
var dialog = electron.dialog;
var BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow();

 mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');
  var url;

  if (os.platform() == 'darwin') {
    autoUpdater.on('error', function (error) {
      dialog.showMessageBox(mainWindow, {
        buttons: [],
        title: 'Error',
        message: JSON.stringify(error)
      });
    });

    url = 'https://www.office.dok32.com/dental/appversion/check.json?version=' + app.getVersion();
  }

  autoUpdater.setFeedURL(url);
  autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
}
```

and it returns empty error object when setFeedURL call's.

{"sender":{"_events":{},"_eventsCount":3}}

What I do wrong?

Comment: Does the `autoUpdater` work if you use `process.platform === 'darwin'` instead of `os.platform() == 'darwin'`?

Comment: I forgot to include this line of code:    `var os = require('os');`

Comment: So that solved your problem?

Comment: No, i signed now the app, but from time it returns this error again

Comment: instead of 'from time' read 'after a while'